# Should the answers made a little more generic, when possible?

Tags: discussion

We have a question about the usage of *I* versus *me*, and a question about *they* versus *them*.
The questions are similar, as in both the cases the question is about when to use a personal pronoun in the subjective case, or in the objective case.

It would be good if the answer for the first question would report a sentence like *you use "I" (and similarly, "he", "she", "we", and "they") when […]*; at least the answer would (probably) resolve the doubts about when to use *they* or *them*.

I understand what it's not possible in all the cases, but in some cases it would be useful (for who asked the question) to specify if the answer is valid for the specific case, or it's part of a generic case.

What do you think?

Comment: would it not make more sense to make the *question* more generic, instead? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own opinion is that it's OK to make answers somewhat more generic, as long as it does not become confusing to the original poster, and that the specific case they asked about is still explicitly solved. It's fine, in your example, to talk in general about the difference between personal pronouns in various cases, but you would still need to say somewhere whether it should be *I* or *me* in the case they asked about.